# How to set and use a variable with iframes?

Tags: javascript, variables, cookies, iframe

I've written a little webpage that enables split-screen viewing in any iframe-enabled browser.  It has back buttons, forward buttons, home buttons, and links to Bing and Google.  What I'm trying to figure out is how to store a homepage value input by the user.  I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this; I've tried several tutorials for setting variables in cookies. (Cookies are the right way to do that, right?)

[This](http://twobrowse.cogizio.org/) is the page so far.  I want to remove the Bing and Google buttons and replace them both with a "Set as Home" button to the right of the Go button.  What javascript, CSS, and HTML magic am I missing here?

The person whose work gets this done will be credited on the page, both on the iframe's home page and in the main page's source code.

Comment: Are you looking for http://www.odesk.com/?

Comment: To clarify: no, I'm more of aspiring, and I do actually seek to understand the code.  I haven't actually learned much javascript.

Answer (score 1):

To encourage you to actually do the coding *yourself* rather than [copy-and-pasting snippets from the Internet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_and_paste_programming), I will describe the way I would do it, leaving it to you to write the actual code. The [jQuery documentation site](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) is very well-written and helpful, but you also need to know the [basics of JavaScript programming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) to write real scripts.

1. The [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/raw/master/jquery.cookie.js) can help (documentation is in the source code). Example:

   ```
   // Setting the cookie
   $.cookie('url1', 'http://www.google.com', { expires: 999 });


   // Reading the cookie
   alert($.cookie('url1'));
   ```
2. jQuery allows you to easily attach event handlers to elements, such as [when an element is clicked](http://api.jquery.com/click/) (to perform an action when the "Set home page" button is clicked, for example).

   It also allows you to [get values of form fields](http://api.jquery.com/val/) (to get the URL to set the home page to), [set the `src` URL of an iframe](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), and [run code when the page has loaded](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) (the latter two to load the home pages in the iframes when the user opens the outer page).

   You're already using all this in the snippet you lifted for the Go button; it's definitely easy enough for *any* programmer to add cookie storage (use variables and an if statement to take different actions depending on whether the user has selected a home page).
3. Because of the [same-origin policy](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Same-origin_policy_for_DOM_access) used to protect user privacy and security on the web, it's not possible to get the URL of a page loaded in the iframe. You would only be able to add support for setting the home page URL to what is inside the text box.

Comment: That Wikipedia article was a nice read.  It's time to get to work--thanks idealmachine, I'll try my best.